# Cultural heritage participatory platform with photo uploading and 3D reconstruction - Django with Visual SfM?

Tags: photography, framework, 3d

I have to realize for a project a sort of cultural heritage platform where people can upload their photos for a specific cultural point of interest, then use these photos to realize a 3D visualization of the point and show the reconstruction to users, whenever they look on the map about that place.

I have some doubts about the frameworks and software that are best to use: for now, I was told to check if Django framework could be the best to support this project, but since I have never use it, it is hard to tell. I gave it a try, but obviously with simple tutorials, so I'm wondering if I can proceed this way or if there's better choices that could better support the idea (with plugins or more specific tools, I guess).

Also, for 3D reconstruction, I've tried Visual SfM, a tool that is Bundler - based, and I'm wondering if it also could be the best choice to perform the task of 3D reconstruction together with Django.

Are there any good practices that I can follow? Or is it all up to the programmer and the way he prefers?